# splice alternative - Move elements from a list without removing them from the original list

Tags: c++

I want to merge one list with another into another list. At the moment I use this:

```
v_unique_sorted_list = v_list;
v_unique_sorted_list.splice(v_unique_sorted_list.end(), u_list);
v_unique_sorted_list.sort();
v_unique_sorted_list.unique();
```

I want the same but without removing the elements from `u_list`. Is there an alternative or I have to use a loop and `insert`?

Comment: Make a copy of `u_list`?

Comment: @LogicStuff use something like a temp list. It could work...

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the tools you're working with before asking questions like this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the 4th `std::list::insert` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) which will do the looping for you and it will not affect `u_list`:

```
v_unique_sorted_list.insert(v_unique_sorted_list.end(),
                            u_list.begin(), u_list.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy the elements of `u_list` into `v_unique_sorted_list` then just use [`std::list::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)

```
v_unique_sorted_list = v_list;
v_unique_sorted_list.insert(v_unique_sorted_list.end(), u_list.begin(), u_list.end());
v_unique_sorted_list.sort();
v_unique_sorted_list.unique();
```

This will copy the element in `u_list` to `v_unique_sorted_list` and insert them before `v_unique_sorted_list.end()`.  This is a linear operation and leaves `u_list` unmodified.